# Difference between jni and cpp packages in android project

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

What is the difference between *jni* and *cpp* packages in a project with Android NDK? It seems that *.cpp*, *.h*, *Android.mk* and other files for work with native code can be located in both packages? .. Or am I wrong? What then is their difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are really just folders, so it's up to you how you organize your native code as long as you specify the correct path to your source and include files in the build system (i.e. your **CMakeLists.txt** or **Android.mk** file). That being said, Android Studio 3.1 seems to put all native code to the `cpp/` folder by default, so it'd be logical to use the `jni/` folder for jni headers only or not use it at all.